# Java method invocation ambigious for javac but not for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

Try to compile the following Test.java source file:

```
interface A<K> {
    void method(K k);
}

interface B {
    void method(Integer k);
}

interface C extends A<Integer>, B {
}

class D implements C {
    public void method(Integer i) {}
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        C c = new D();
        c.method(Integer.valueOf(0));
    }
}
```

The method call c.method() is declared ambigious by javac, but not by Eclipse. I've seen several examples of this kind of problems on StackOverflow (javac gives an error, Eclipse doesn't) but in this specific case I really don't understand how the call can be considered ambiguous, given that the compiler compiles interface C.

Who's right?

This example fails with both Java 8 and Java 9. Note that making the method explicit:

```
interface C extends A<Integer>, B {
    void method(Integer k);
}
```

makes the code compilable, which is quite weird, as the interface is exactly the same.

Comment: even though both methods seem to have the same parameters (Integer and Integer), they are different methods. One can implement both methods by declaring one method in D, but that still doesnt solve the problem of which method is called. An instance declared as A or B can execute the function

Comment: @Wietlol *One can implement both methods by declaring one method in D, but that still doesnt solve the problem of which method is called.* It absolutely does. An instance can only have one implementation of a given method signature, and it's perfectly clear where to find that. The fact that the definitions are repeated in multiple interfaces is irrelevant. This can be proven by making `A` and `B` identical, with `C extends A, B`.

Comment: @Wietlol To put it a little differently, overload ambiguity is about which *signature* is most appropriate for a given method invocation, not which *class* contains a particular method signature.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has just acknowledged that this appears to be a bug.

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8177440